# NodeJS: How to do nightmareJS e2e-testing on running docker application

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, docker, nightmare

I am creating a docker image/container for testing purpose from my productive build application (nodeJS app).
Now I want to do some e2e testing using **mocha/chai** and **nightmareJS**. So I have created a very basic test file.

My problem is now how to test for the running application. So I want to 'load' the application like

```
- goto http://localhost
- check if login form is existing
- do login
- check if login was successful
```

I don't know how to do this in my docker image / e2e.js-file...

This is how I'm creating the docker image:

**Dockerfile**

```
# Use the production image as base image
FROM productive_build:latest

# Copy the test files
COPY e2e.js /

# Override the NODE_ENV environment variable to 'dev', in order to get required test packages
ENV NODE_ENV dev

# 1. Get test packages; AND
# 2. Install our test framework - mocha
RUN (cd programs/server && npm install)
RUN npm install -g mocha
RUN npm install chai nightmare

# Override the command, to run the test instead of the application
CMD ["mocha", "e2e.js", "--reporter", "spec"]
```

And this is how my basic e2e.js file looks like:

**e2e.js**

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare'),
    expect = require('chai').expect

describe('test', function () {
  it('should always be true', function () {
    var nightmare = Nightmare()
    nightmare.end()
    expect(true).to.be.true
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure by looking at your `Dockerfile`, but by looking at your comment

> Override the command, to run the test instead of the application

You'll still need to launch the website in itself after having installed it's dependencies, and then mocha. Since docker is only intended to run one process at a time you might want to look at [supervisord](http://supervisord.org), but you can also put your website as a background process and then launch your test.

Using an entrypoint to a bash script instead of your `CMD`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/run.sh"]
```

And the script in itself would be something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
npm start & mocha e2e.js --reporter spec
```

As for the test in itself, you can do something like this to test your login flow. It's only an example, you might need to tweak a few things, like the elements selectors and some other stuff but it's still a good starting point.

```js
var Nightmare = require('nightmare')
var expect = require('chai').expect

describe('test login', function () {

 it('should login and display my username', function (done) {
    var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false })

    nightmare
      .goto('http://localhost:8000') // your local url with the correct port
      .type('#login', 'your login') // change value of the login input
      .type('#password', 'your password')
      .click('#submit') // click the submit button
      .wait('#my-username') // wait for this element to appear (page loaded)
      .evaluate(function () {
        // query something once logged on the page
        return document.querySelector('#my-username').innerText
      })
      .end()
      .then(function (result) {
        // the result will be the thing you grabbed from the window in the evaluate
        expect(result).to.equal('user3142695')
        done()
      })
      .catch(done)

  })

})
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is exactly, what I am looking for. Just one more question: Where should I put the script? Do I have to add `COPY run.sh /` and then use `ENTRYPOINT ["run.sh"]`?

Comment: And how do I know the correct port which is used for localhost?

Comment: Yes you have to copy the script into the container, if you put it in / you might have to add one to the command though. As for the port, you just need to specify the same url where you are going while developing locally

Answer (score 0):

> Qualifier: I don't know **nightmarejs** or all of your dependencies

You'll need a monitoring tool for **node.js**. **nodemon** is a good option and Docker has a tutorial on using **nodemon** and **Visual Studio Code** to live debug a node.js app.

Here's the tutorial:
https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/developer-tools/nodejs-debugging/VSCode-README.md